# How to make an object land on the same side in corona

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk, gravity

Say there is this cube and there is a platform, the cube jumps on the platform but it lands just on the corner and gravity makes it fall. The cube will rotate and the bottom side will be different.

How do I make it so that the cube always lands on the same side?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a function that updates the cube's rotation to 0 every frame:

```
local function noRotate(event)
cube.rotation=0
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", noRotate)
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I hope it helps!

Comment: This did make it better but whenever the cube falls from a high place, gravity causes it to turn sideways and fall on its side (Assuming the cube is moving when it falls).

Comment: The cube still rotates when you add this function in?

Answer (score 0):

For sake of performance you should use built in parameter for related physics object.

CubeObject.isFixedRotation = true